# List of common docstring :types for pycharm

Tags: python, types, pycharm

Pycharm has a nice feature, whereby it reads the type declaration within a function docstring and does correct-usage checks where that function is used.

Is there a nice resource, that lists rules and names for all commonly used types?

**Note:**
I have provided an answer below, with everything that I have been able to figure out. Its far from comprehensive, though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the list of types I commonly use:

```
string:             str
unicode:            unicode
integer:            int
float:              float
general dictionary: dict
general list:       list
general tuple:      tuple
None:               None
not defined:        Any
your own object:    MySpecialClass

specific tuple:     (str, int)
specific list:      list of str
specific dict:      dict[str, int]
multiple options:   str or list
```

Example:

```
import requests
def example_function(list_var, str_var, num_var, request_var):
    """One line function explanation.

    :param list_var:
    :type list_var: list of str
    :param str_var:
    :type str_var: str or unicode
    :param num_var:
    :type num_var: int
    :param request_var:
    :type request_var: requests.models.Request
    :return:
    :rtype: (list of dict) or None
    """
    return [{}]


example_function(
    ['a', 'b'],
    u'unicode accepted because stated',
    1.234,
    requests.Request('GET', 'http://going/somewhere')
)
```

Correct format for Request was found by following module and class from `__init__.py`

Then, when one presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hovers over the function call, one gets a type-help text.  This is very useful, since [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions are type-vague by design.

In this case, the help text will be:

```
Inferred type: (list_var: List[str], str_var: Union[str, unicode], num_var: int, request_var: Request) -> Optional[List[dict]]
```

And a warning for the `num_var` argument:

```
Expected type 'int', got 'float'
```

Comment: bool type? as in boolean?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an excerpt from [README-obsolete.md](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons/blob/master/README-obsolete.md#types) *Types* section, [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175607/8554766) by [user2235698](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235698/user2235698)):

```
Foo                # Class Foo visible in the current scope
x.y.Bar            # Class Bar from x.y module
Foo | Bar          # Foo or Bar
(Foo, Bar)         # Tuple of Foo and Bar
list[Foo]          # List of Foo elements
dict[Foo, Bar]     # Dict from Foo to Bar
T                  # Generic type (T-Z are reserved for generics)
T <= Foo           # Generic type with upper bound Foo
Foo[T]             # Foo parameterized with T
(Foo, Bar) -> Baz  # Function of Foo and Bar that returns Baz

unknown            # Unknown type
None               # type(None)
string             # Py2: str | unicode, Py3: str
bytestring         # Py2: str | unicode, Py3: bytes
bytes              # Py2: str, Py3: bytes
unicode            # Py2: unicode, Py3: str
```

By the way: there is also section mentioning *Type Hinting*, in the [PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is [repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons) on GitHub with python skeletons. README contains possible type declarations.